# Empty value option in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I am trying to create a select dropdown that models to a specific parameter inside an object that is part of an array however I want the "null value" parameter to actually have a value (or to simply be able to insert an extra option in the dropdown).

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="question.defaultGoToQuestion" ng-options="question.sequence as question.questionHeading for question in survey.questions">
  <option value="-1">Finish</option>
</select>
```

However angular simply ignores the  inside the select tag unless it has a null value `value=""`. How can I go about always having the option with `value of -1` regardless of what is inside the `survey.questions` array?

I also forgot to mention that the `-1` should be an integer so that the model can be always associated to integer values and not strings.

## Quick update

I would like to have something almost exactly like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="question.defaultGoToQuestion" ng-options="question.sequence as question.questionHeading for question in survey.questions">
  <option value="">Finish</option>
</select>
```

Except I need finish to have a `-1` value in the finish option.

Comment: Which options you want to be there in the select box ?

Comment: In the select box I need to see a list of survey questions + an option that says finish and has a value of  "-1". It is worth noting that survey.questions can be changed through the UI and the $scope.survey variable is updated accordingly. (I'll update the question since I dont know how to post code in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like this to specify the key/value pairs, you can assign the values you want:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option for (key, value) in options"></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.options = {
    'select': -1,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6
   };

$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[0];
```

Comment: The problem with that is the options change and I already go through the effort of tidying up all my objects from my controller/factory. I just want to reuse the information I already have with an extra <option> in the select dropdown. I would prefer not to have yet another variable to represent the data that is already present in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit counter intuitive that you need the model to have a value yet doesn't want it to have it defined in the data structure.

For one way you can add the element to the beginning of your data array using `unshift`

```
$scope.survey.questions.unshift({sequence: -1, questionHeading: 'Finish'});
$scope.question.defaultGoToQuestion = $scope.survey.questions[0];
```

Comment: Someone did mention this method before but seems they have deleted their answer. It seems this might be the way about this. The only issue I have is that these questions are displayed in the page and adding a question to the array also means it will be visible unless I specifically target it not to be. I would think this is not the ideal way about it in my head but it's possible I am oversimplifying things. What is odd to me is that the "default" option can be overwritten the angular way but it has to have a null value.

Comment: If you want the default behavior of the angular select placeholder (ie the option disappear after user selecting a value) have you considered setting the -1 only when you are going to submit?

Comment: I think you are right on the money and I think that will be the solution right now. When submitting, if the value is null I will change it to -1.